# Cannot run php from command line when use environment variable

Tags: php, installation

I have windows 8, and whenever I run php from the installed directory, then it works without a problem, but whenever I set the environment variable to that directory, and run `php --version`, then a win-8 bar appears:

> This app can't run on your PC
>  To find a version for your PC,
>   check with the software publisher

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution for this?

Attached below are the commands that i ran:

```
K:\Users\username>php
Access is denied.

K:\Users\username>php
Access is denied.

K:\Users\username>php --version
Access is denied.

K:\Users\username>F:/
'F:/' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

K:\Users\username>F:

F:\>php
Access is denied.

F:\>cd Program

F:\Program>cd php-5.5.6-x86 

F:\Program\php-5.5.6-x86>ls
dev            iculx51.dll             libpq.dll         php.gif
ext            icutest51.dll           libsasl.dll       php.ini-development
extras         icutu51.dll             license.txt       php.ini-production
glib-2.dll     icuuc51.dll             news.txt          php5.dll
gmodule-2.dll  install.txt             phar.phar.bat     readme-redist-bins.txt
icudt51.dll    libeay32.dll            pharcommand.phar  snapshot.txt
icuin51.dll    libenchant.dll          php-cgi.exe       ssleay32.dll
icuio51.dll    libenchant_ispell.dll   php-win.exe
icule51.dll    libenchant_myspell.dll  php.exe

F:\Program\php-5.5.6-x86>php --version
PHP 5.5.6 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2013 11:33:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

F:\Program\php-5.5.6-x86>
```

By the way the same thing occurs in wampserver php, so it probably dont have anything to do with 86 bit install or 5.5.6 unstable.

I also tried run as admin not working either, same output.

Comment: What is "the environment variable"? There are multiple ones (in fact unlimited...) - which one are you talking about? Is the typo in "version" just in yout post (you wrote "verion") or did you make the same typo in the console? Have you restarted the console after changing any environment variables - and how did you change it?

Comment: What happens if you try to run some other command? Like php -f test.php or whatever else?

Comment: As @JohannesH. said, the proper variable to put the path of php would be `PATH` then you have to run the console as administrator. Try that and let us know.

Comment: F:\Program\php-5.5.6-x86; is the path that I've entered, this should be correct?

Comment: How should I know, you can install PHP wherever you like ;) But make sure path really includes that directory in your current shell, if the shell was open the whole time, it won't reload the variables. Those always represent the environment the way it was when the console was started (unless you cahnged it inside the console, than the change is only there, and will be lost once you colse it). That's why I asekd how you did it and what exatly you did.

Comment: ok, so i removed the only reference i have in environment variable and still in console when enter php --version i get access is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have two PHP executables, one of them (F:\Program\php-5.5.6-x86\php.exe) is working, one of them (which is on your path) is not. Check the directories in your PATH for the broken one.

Comment: yep, u've got it, apparently running a bat file from the php source left a php.exe inside my system root.i went through the directories one by one and finally found the issue after 2 hrs of research..

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue before and tried several things, one of the things that works for me that the php.exe file has been changed by some program and it's size was 0 kb, I reverted back by bringing the php.exe file from backup folder I have.

may be it is not solution for all people, but just check the php file hasn't been changed.